# Prime factors, help understand the use of square root

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, logic, prime-factoring

Following the solution given on geeks for geeks website for finding prime factors, I don't really follow why they use the square root of n on line 16 (for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2):    )

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/

```
# Python program to print prime factors 

import math 

# A function to print all prime factors of 
# a given number n 
def primeFactors(n): 
    
    # Print the number of two's that divide n 
    while n % 2 == 0: 
        print 2, 
        n = n / 2
        
    # n must be odd at this point 
    # so a skip of 2 ( i = i + 2) can be used 
    for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2): 
        
        # while i divides n , print i ad divide n 
        while n % i== 0: 
            print i, 
            n = n / i 
            
    # Condition if n is a prime 
    # number greater than 2 
    if n > 2: 
        print n
```

this is the logic im having trouble following, if someone could understand the counter example given below.

> Every composite number has at least one prime factor less than or equal to square root of itself.
> This property can be proved using counter statement. Let a and b be two factors of n such that a*b = n. If both are greater than √n, then a.b > √n, * √n, which contradicts the expression “a * b = n”.

Comment: One more reason not to use geeksforgeeks... that paragraph is awfully written...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple arithmetic. If `r` is the square root of `n`, then `r * r == n`. If you multiply `r` by anything larger than it, the result will be larger than `n`. So there can't be any other prime factor larger than `r`.

So there's no point in continuing the loop past the square root, since it can never find anything there.

Comment: and as for the loop, does it use the root as there aren't any possible higher factors?

Comment: That's correct. We stop because we know we've found all the possible roots.

Comment: Awesome I understand it now thanks for taking the time to explain, helped out alot!